# Apache blocking the download of jar file

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, java-web-start

I have created java web start program and it is getting deployed on tomcat. In my local it is working fine. In my qa server, I have apache on front of tomcat and tomcat is listening on ajp port. When I try to download the jar file it is not downloading. Any idea how to handle this, my applet is on webapps/ROOT/applet folder of tomcat and I am ajp proxying from apache to tomcat.

I am using tomcat 8 and apache 2.5

Comment: *"When I try to download the jar file it is not downloading."* ..fix the server? What error code is the server providing when you try to load the resource using your browser?